# When update profile do a INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a log that registers an increase of a custom profile field of users, the field is the "balance"

All users in wordpress have this field, and administrators can only increase the value, but I want to record all this increases.

I just created a custom table on the database with the following stucture:

```
======================================
 ID | OPERATOR | USER | VALUE | DATE
======================================
```

Resultados da pesquisa
Resultado da tradução

So I've tried to insert values on this custom database table when the custom field is saved, all profile fields are updated with no problem, but the INSERT is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'saldo', $_POST['saldo'] + $_POST['saldo_add'] );


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO speedgo_lancamento VALUES ('', " . $_POST['operator'] . ", " . $_POST['checkuser_id'] . ", '" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "', " . $_POST['balance_add'] + $_POST['balance'] . ")";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}
```

Comment: Your table has `VALUE, DATE`, but your query order is `date(), balance_add`?

Comment: enclose `( $_POST['balance_add'] + $_POST['balance'] )`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @ACD That stuff shouldn't be embedded in the query in the first place.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Since you're using WordPress, why is `mysqli` involved here at all? WordPress already has its own database layer called [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is wrong as MySQL only accepts dates in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` format. Try `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in your query instead of `date('d/m/Y H:i:s')`.

**Example**

Try changing

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO speedgo_lancamento VALUES ('', " . $_POST['operator'] . ", " . $_POST['checkuser_id'] . ", '" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "', " . $_POST['balance_add'] + $_POST['balance'] . ")";
```

To

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO speedgo_lancamento VALUES ('', " . $_POST['operator'] . ", " . $_POST['checkuser_id'] . ", '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "', " . $_POST['balance_add'] + $_POST['balance'] . ")";
```